# How to do oracle TNSPING with java?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a details of Database `TNSEntries`. I need to code in Java to check the `TNSPING`. Is there anyway to do that?

Sample `TNSENtry`:

```
orcldb=
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = myservice)
  (INSTANCE_NAME = myinstance)
)
)
```

I have done oracle connection with username and password using jdbc oracle driver. This TNSPING is new to me and it doesn't have username and password. could you please anyone help to code TNSPING in java?

Comment: You can connect to database with random username and password and check if ORA-01017 (invalid username/password) is returned - if it is so then your DB is up and running, otherwise there is some kind of problem with DB or network connectivity

Comment: `tnsping` is an OS command.  Probably the standard way of doing this would be a shell script running `grep` on the `tnsnames.ora` file and pinging the services in a loop.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I'm getting ORA-01017 with random username and password, but is there any other way around it? Sometimes DB will get lock with wrong credential attempts  (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: why do you need it? tnsping is diagnostic tool. it is not intended to daily business

Answer (score 4):

TNSPING validates only network connection to Listener process, you don't need to pass username and password.

As @KonstantinV.Salikhov says, you may code a tool like the following, it will verify:

.- Network connection to listener process (if listener is UP or not like TNSPING would do)
.- Database service is UP or not (as TNSPING would identify database service name).

The tool will not use username/password as we only need the login failure event to validate that database is up and running.

JAVA CODE:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.*;

public class ThinTnsnames {

    static String sql = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String entry_name = args[0];
        test(entry_name);
    }

    public static void test(String entry_name) {
        Connection pconnection = null;
        try {
            String l_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + entry_name;
            System.out.println( "Connection string = " + l_url );

            OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
            ods.setURL(l_url);
            pconnection = ods.getConnection ();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            int errorCode = e.getErrorCode() ;
            System.err.println("Error Code: " + errorCode) ;
            if ( errorCode == 12514 ) {
                System.err.println("Listener is UP but database is DOWN");
            }
            if ( errorCode == 17002 ) {
                System.err.println("Listener is DOWN");
            }
           if ( errorCode == 1017 ) {
                System.err.println("Listener is UP and database is UP");
            }
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if ( pconnection != null ) {
                    pconnection .close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use your own tnsnames.ora file in another directory to test it, for example in "/home/oracle/2" directory:

```
[oracle@ora12c 2]$ cat /home/oracle/2/tnsnames.ora

orcldb =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora12c.node.com)(PORT = 15300))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = db02.node.com)
      (INSTANCE_NAME = db02)
    )
  )
```

And then you invoke it this way:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_71
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export CLASSPATH=/home/oracle/2/ojdbc7.jar:.

java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=/home/oracle/2 ThinTnsnames orcldb
```

Possible outputs are:

```
Connection string = jdbc:oracle:thin:@orcldb
Error Code: 1017
Listener is UP and database is UP

Connection string = jdbc:oracle:thin:@orcldb
Error Code: 12514
Listener is UP but database is DOWN

Connection string = jdbc:oracle:thin:@orcldb
Error Code: 17002
Listener is DOWN
```

You can verify that no username is being used during connection by querying dba_audit_trail view as follows:

```
select username,action_name,returncode from dba_audit_trail
where action_name like 'LOG%' ;

USERNAME             ACTION_NAME                  RETURNCODE
-------------------- ---------------------------- ----------
                     LOGON                              1017
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your effort. This code will try to connect the database with dummy user id and password and database will throw error and based on the error this code is identifying the outputs. My question is whether database wont get lock if try to connect wrong credentials?

Comment: @Mohan No, this code is not using a username to login. It just sends a "blank" username so there's no possibility to lock any database account. I've updated my answer noting this information.