# Why is my Docker-Compose getting stuck after initializing my oracle database and doesn't proceed to the next service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, weblogic12c, oracle19c

I am trying to update the docker of my project using docker compose, using the Oracle Database 19c Enterprise edition, WebLogic Server 12.1.4 and the Java Server JRE for java 8.
I have written a script that creates the base images for the DB and weblogic server and then proceeds to use the docker-compose up for the yaml that I have written.

The structure of the projects consists of the oracle base images, pulled from the official oracle images on github, and then I have created my own Dockerfiles to extend these images. My issue is on the Oracle DB Dockerfile, where I am not sure on how to proceed. At this point the installation gets stuck after completing the database and doesnt proceed to weblogic installation and not even creating a seperate container..

```
ENV ORACLE_PWD="password"

ENV ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1
ADD db-assets /tmp/db-assets

COPY ./wait_db.sh $ORACLE_BASE/
COPY ./runDBscripts.sh $ORACLE_BASE/
COPY ./runOracle.sh $ORACLE_BASE/
COPY ./startDB.sh $ORACLE_BASE/

USER root
RUN chmod ug+x $ORACLE_BASE/*.sh      

USER oracle

RUN $ORACLE_BASE/runOracle.sh &&\
    $ORACLE_BASE/wait_db.sh && \
    $ORACLE_BASE/runDBscripts.sh
    
CMD $ORACLE_BASE/wait_db.sh
```

I have tried a bunch of combinations to get this working. Have I added any commands where there shouldn't have been?
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:

  db:
    build:
      context: db/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: oracle/database
    ports:
      - "10000:1521"
      - "10001:22"
    shm_size: 1G

  app:
    build:
      context: app/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.4
    ports:
      - 10003:7001
      - 10004:7002
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "
        echo sleeping while db is starting;
        sleep 90;
        #script for starting a managed server on weblogic@
      "
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to make this work and it really frustrates me that I can't get it right. Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: if your db image has `CMD $ORACLE_BASE/wait_db.sh`, that is exactly what gets executed when docker-compose `up`s the service. You probably want the original container ENTRYPOINT or CMD there (which presumably, start the db server). Please post the whole `Dockerfile`, not just this snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is my dockerfile for the extending image, the dockerfile for the oracle image can be found here https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/19.3.0/Dockerfile.

When I used the ```CMD start_db.sh``` script the compose would get stuck after the DB installation(saying that the database is ready to use) however, when I use the ``` CMD wait_db.sh``` the compose proceeds to start the weblogic part but BEFORE the database has complete its installation and I think both are wrong

Comment: Yes, both things are a preblem. Your `CMD` override is rendering the image unusable. Besides this, obviously, no amount of waiting on the DB side will make sure that your DB is ready for your app to start. the "wait" logic must be run on the app side (I guess that this is the intention of the crude `sleep 90`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! I was making things way more complicated, my solution is to make the Dockerfile as simple as possible, only copying the database scripts. and switching to user oracle. I also followed this post [How do I check if Oracle is up in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217637/how-do-i-check-if-oracle-is-up-in-docker)
to setup the healthcheck and everything works perfectly.

Comment: +1 because your comment "and switching to user oracle" helped me understand where the bug in my Dockerfile was coming from :)